# Making form fields - read only or disabled in DJANGO updateView

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a model which I will update using an updateView generic class based function. How can I make specific fields as read only ?

example :

**Models.py:**

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    emp_no = models.IntegerField( primary_key=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    hire_date = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('employee')
        verbose_name_plural = ('employees')
        # db_table = 'employees'

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

**views.py :**

```
class EmployeeUpdate(UpdateView):
    
    
    model = Employee
    fields = '__all__'
```

How can I make the first_name readonly inside a UpdateView ?
Note: I want to have the model(charfield) the same, But it should be read only inide an UpdateView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When one wants to customize their forms the easiest way is to make a form class. A generic view is not really meant to provide all features a form class does, even though it makes life a little easy by generating the form for you by itself.

You want to be using a [`ModelForm` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) and set [`disabled=True` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#disabled) on your field:

```
from django import forms

class EmployeeUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=14, disabled=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__'
```

> **Note**: The **disabled** boolean argument, when set to **True**, disables a form field using the **disabled** HTML attribute so that it won’t be
> editable by users. Even if a user tampers with the field’s value
> submitted to the server, it will be ignored in favor of the value from
> the form’s initial data.

Now in your view you simply want to set the `form_class` attribute:

```
class EmployeeUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Employee
    form_class = EmployeeUpdateForm
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for. I saw this in few other sites but couldn't understand. Thanks it worked !!

Comment: is there a way to set all fields as read-only / disabled without explicitly declaring each field in the form class?  if you have a form with 50 fields for example and you want them all read-only, is there a way to say "for field in fields: disabled=True"