# Django UpdateView set read only field by user permission

Tags: django

I have seen some posts like [Making form fields - read only or disabled in DJANGO updateView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66577264/making-form-fields-read-only-or-disabled-in-django-updateview) use custom form on an UpdateView to make some fields as read only fields. However, the form object is not accessible for request.user object. If I want to make some fields read-only only for some user group, is there way to do it under UpdateView?

Answer (score 0):

Got same question and find next solution.
I use Django 4.2 and don't know is this solution valid for older version.

My project use UpdateView and class based views. So for my view was limited displayed fields. After that I can change only this field but I find that I still can use reference to object params from it model.

view.py:

```
class UpdateEventView(UpdateView):
    model = Events
    fields = ['user']
    template_name = 'update-event.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('app:events')
    
    @method_decorator(user_passes_test(lambda user: user.is_superuser, login_url='/'))
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(UpdateEventView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

and template part:

```
<h1 class="page__data">Update event for: {{ events.event_date }}</h1>
<div class="page__text">
    <form class="form" method="POST" action="{% url 'app:edit' events.uuid %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
</div>
```

As a result user can see event_date on page but can't change it. May be it can solve your question. Just try to do different view for user with limited access. Well... "Just" :)